# node connection to mysql db problems using node-orm

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm

When I use connection without node-orm with node-mysql from [this example](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction) works. But when I try to make smth like [this](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm#connecting-via-raw-database-api) it crashes. As i understood orm redesigned their api but haven't editted their wiki.

However this:

```
var db = orm.connect("mysql://username:password@hostname/database", function (success, db) {...});
```

dont crash but success is null too :(

How should I connect with orm to mysql?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the old orm, Use [orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) Which will use the syntax
`orm.connect("mysql://username:password@host/database", function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;`

Answer (score 0):

Had some issues with node-orm. Magic undebuggable errors...
Try this: https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm (okey for simple dbs)